# How to remotely start and stop a service by Port number?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, scripting, pipe

I have a file containing IP addresses and port numbers only. I know how to start a service by its name but how to start and stop it by port number?

```
for port in $(cat /home/asd/iplog.txt); do
    service /etc/init.d/$port | cut -d\: -f2 start
done
```

here is the iplog.txt output:

```
192.168.1.2:21
192.168.2.25:80
192.168.5.230:25
```

and the output of the script:

```
/etc/init.d/192.168.1.2:21: unrecognized service
cut: start: no such file or directory
/etc/init.d/192.168.2.25:80: unrecognized service
cut: start: no such file or directory
```

Now I have two questions:

- How to start and stop a service by its port number?
- how to do it remotely?

as I am not familiar with shell scripting, I really need your help please.

Comment: I think, the approach is inherently flawed: for any sensible system to function, services should be known, sometimes services should be started or stopped in a certain order, etc. Make use of some orchestration solution, eg, Salt, to manage your service.

Answer (score 0):

**How to find a service's PID/command by its port number?**

You can kill it/them to stop the service. But this is not the best way.

```
#lsof-i :22
Command   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    14543 root    3u  IPv4 4132251      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    14543 root    4u  IPv6 4132253      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
#ps 14543
PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
14543 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
```

**how to do it remotely?**

```
ssh user@remote 'your command to stop service'
```

Comment: "lsof -i :port" only shows whether a service is running or not. It is not starting or stopping a service right?

Comment: @RAZHamraz right. It returns the PID if the service is running. With this PID, you can find the command line. Then start or stop it as you wish. E.g. ps -p 1453 -o comm=  it returns "sshd"

Comment: @RAZHamraz As Roman Susi mentioned, you'd better identify which service listen on those ports and what's the right command to check its status/start/stop.